# Is there a way to feed multiple audio interfaces with Web Audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api, webkitaudiocontext

I am currently thinking about how to realise an app that feeds multiple audio interfaces with different sounds. For example if I have a second sound card at disposal.

As far as I researched the AudioContext of Web Audio only feeds a single destination. I haven't seen a way to select the actual destination hardware.

Can anyone think of a way to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. It'll use whatever your system default is.

Comment: OK, thats really sad. Could there be a way to work around it by rerouting the output to another (maybe even browser specific) API?

Comment: It might help to know what the specific use-case is here. But as far as I know, there's no way to get support for multiple destinations with the Web Audio API.

Comment: The basic idea is to have a monitoring output for a sound mixer, so that I can prelisten a second track.

Comment: Depending on your sound card and the way you've got things hooked up, you might be able to sort of fake it with the surround mixing capabilities of the Web Audio API. Like, send the "real" mix to Front L/R, and put the stuff you want to prelisten in Rear L/R.

Comment: I checked my external Audio interface, which has a stereo output and a stereo headphones output. It reports with maxChannelsCount 4, so I guess it should work out somehow.

Comment: @David, I'd be interested to know what solution you used, as this is a basic feature of many types of hardware.

Comment: @PhoenixStormcrow I finally took an audio interface with two outputs. They show up as 2x2 channels. I didn't implement the monitor output I wanted till now. Time...

Answer (score 1):

You can output audio from an audio/video element to a specified output device using setSinkid()

videoElement.setSinkId(deviceID).then().catch()